# break button_click event when enter pressed

Tags: c#, buttonclick, eventargs, keyeventargs

Is an easy way to cancel click event when user hit enter on button (instead of mouse click on button?)

i have tried with:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs ke = e as KeyEventArgs;
        if (ke != null)
        {
            if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

But ke is null

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this. This is a standard feature of how Windows programs work and you should strive to stay with the norm (except in some unusual situations). If you don't want it to be the default button then you can remove that from the Form's properties.

Comment: I'm using barcode scanner in my winform. I have set up scanner to hit enter after every scan. But if button of form has focus and user scan an barcode, button will do click event (because barcode scanner scan code and 'hit' enter)

Comment: I would think a better approach would be to disable the button until a valid input is entered via whatever text box. This would prevent accidental "clicking" with the scanner and would still maintain a standard that users have come to expect with WinForms. I know many users prefer to use a keyboard over a mouse (I often do) and disabling the enter button would annoy them.

Comment: In this form user must scan few barcodes, and set few things on comboboxes, listboxes and other windows, so all of controls must be enabled during this operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool IsMouse = (e is System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs);

  // If not mouse, they hit spacebar or enter
}
```

Comment: BTW, I remember the way I figured out this solution originally. I ran the code in the debugger and inspected the object type when I ran it using mouse and keyboard to trigger the button and saw that they were different object types. If you use Enter/Space you get the type EventArgs, so you can't test against EventArgs as MouseEventArgs descends from EventArgs

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be null. because `EventArgs` is not `KeyEventArgs`

`KeyEventArgs` will be passed as a parameter to `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` events. You're messing up things.

Comment: Moreover, button3_Click is event handler subscribed for a Click event for the Button class, so it meant that Button is Clicked, not Pressed

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
private bool flag = false;
private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        flag = true;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    //else do original task
}
```

Comment: A bit messy, but propably will work :) Thanks, but @Gary Walker posted in my opinion better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can handle KeyPress event for the button and disable or ignore enter key there instead of returning in button click

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if ((keyData & Keys.KeyCode) == Keys.Enter)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```